# Readonly, non-mutable, public and readwrite, mutable, private @property: more information?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I want to expose an `NSArray` to my user (and I want them to only read it), but in my class, I want to use an `NSMutableArray`.

I tried the following code and it does not raise any warning:

```
// In the .h
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray * test ;

@end
```

and

```
// In the .m
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray * test ;

@end


@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

But, if I try to access the `@property` `test` from within my class, I can use the method `addObject:`. So, I guess what precedes is not possible.

**Why is there no warning as it is?**

Comment: check this http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties.html

Comment: Sure about `NSArray` in header file and `NSMutableArray` in your implementation file?

Comment: Yes this is my point!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that mixing property type would be a good practice. Instead I would create an accessor that returns a copy of the private mutable array. This is more conventional. Please note, don't use self for property access in your `-init:` method:

```
// In the .h
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

- (NSArray *)test;

@end

// In the .m
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *aTest;

@end


@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _aTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSArray *)test
{
    return [self.aTest copy];
}

@end
```

Comment: This would be a very atypical and confusing pattern.  The property should not be readwrite and should not be named the same as the accessor method.   However, that you return a `copy` of the mutable container is correct.

Comment: @bbum: my mistake (typo) and you're right. I've edited my answer to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `@property` is just syntax sugar which automatically creates getter/setter methods for you. With the `readonly` in the `.h` file only the getter method will be created for the public but by overriding it in the `.m` file you get both methods in your implementation.

`readwrite` is the default [(see here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) so even if leave out `readwrite` put still have the `@property` in you implementation file you will get a setter method. It is good practice to explicitly write `readwrite` then in your `.m` file so you and other will get a hint that this variable might only be declared read only in the `.h` file.